# How to get Xcode to show its startup screen again?

Tags: xcode

When I started Xcode I always got a screen that let me choose which project to open, or to start a new project, or a few other options. A few days ago I noticed it had a checkbox that was prechecked that said something like "Always show this screen on startup". Unfortunately, I unchecked it. I thought it would just reopen the last project I was editing but that's not what it does. Now Xcode just launches without opening any window at all so you have to go into its File menu, choose open, and find your project. I want to go back to the previous (default) behavior but I can't find any way to go back.

Does anyone know how to get that opening screen to show again? (It's not in preferences.)

Comment: For Xcode 8: "Window" -> "Welcome to Xcode"

Answer (score 255, accepted):

From Xcode 4 and above versions, it's **"Window" -> "Welcome to Xcode (<kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>)"**.

On the older Xcode 3, it's **"Help" -> "Welcome to Xcode"**.

If you want to see the window every time Xcode starts, please tick "Show this window when Xcode launches":

[image: Show this window when Xcode launches]

Beware that you need to hover over this window to see this checkbox.

Comment: XCODE 5 all of a sudden stopped showing the "Welcome to XCode" and the above solution does work for showing the screen every time, but how to get XCODE to show the screen automatically again.?

Comment: @ort11 In Xcode 5.0.1 on my Mac, it's still the same as Xcode 4. Please check your "Window" menu and find "Welcome to Xcode" there. Then you can check "Show this window when Xcode launches". If you don't see the check box there, please move your mouse cursor on the welcome window, the check box will show up then.

Comment: I find it funny that they reserved shortcut for "Welcome Window". But there is no for say Organizer.

Comment: thanks, it's really annoying when you're not welcomed by xcode

Answer (score 20):

*Step 1*
Start Xcode, go to the top navigation bar called **Window**, click on **Welcome to Xcode** it will show you the project screen:

[image: step 1 photo]

*Step 2*
Look at the bottom of the welcome screen, there will be "*show this window when Xcode launches*", tick it:

[image: step 2 photo]

Comment: you are a life saver :) .